# How to call InViewerSearch programmatically

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I loaded the InViewerSearch extension and can use it through the UI. How to use InViewerSearch through code? Any examples and what are the calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call [Viewer.Search()](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/) method, which will return a list of dbIds with that specific search query.